# VB.Net datagrid import excel cells with color

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagrid view and I import Excel values in this datagrid, but I cannot see back colors of cells. Here is my code and a picture.

How can I also pass colors from Excel to a datagrid?

[[image]

```
Dim cmb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    cmb.HeaderText = "Colum1"
    cmb.Name = "cmb"
    cmb.Items.Add("Select for Main Plot")
    cmb.Items.Add("Select")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb)

    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dts As DataSet
    Dim excel As String
    Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog

    OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"

    If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
    End If

    Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
    Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName

    excel = fi.FullName
    conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
    dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sayfa1$]", conn)
    dts = New DataSet
    dta.Fill(dts, "[Sayfa1$]")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "[Sayfa1$]"
    conn.Close()
```

Comment: OleDbConnection is expected to read the data from your excel file, not the cell formatting and transfer it to a DataGridView. You are on your own here.

Comment: what is your proposal here

Answer (score 0):

As Steve points out… this is something you will have to implement. Since you do not really specify how the coloring scheme works, I will assume that depending on the value in the cell will dictate what color background the cell should have. That is fairly straight forward and can be achieved in numerous ways.

One option is to make a method that simply loops through all the cells in the `DataGridView` and depending on the value of the cell sets its color accordingly. This works however each time a cells value is changed, you will have to re-run the method.

Another option is put this logic in the `CellFormatting` event. This way the color will be applied when the `DataGridView` is initialized with data and also will change if the user changes the cells value.

Since your posted code shows none of this, you may need to adjust the code below to your needs.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
  Dim cellValue As String
  Dim row As DataGridViewRow
  row = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
  If (Not row.IsNewRow) Then
    cellValue = row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
    If (cellValue IsNot Nothing) Then
      row.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Style.BackColor = GetColor(cellValue)
    End If ' ignore empty cells
  End If ' ignore new row
End Sub

Private Function GetColor(colorValue As String) As Color
  Select Case colorValue
    Case "1"
      GetColor = Color.FromArgb(245, 129, 109)
    Case "2"
      GetColor = Color.FromArgb(251, 129, 113)
    Case "3"
      GetColor = Color.FromArgb(252, 155, 119)
    Case "4"
      GetColor = Color.FromArgb(250, 186, 119)
    Case "5"
      GetColor = Color.FromArgb(253, 208, 130)
    Case "6"
      GetColor = Color.FromArgb(253, 236, 129)
    Case "7"
      GetColor = Color.FromArgb(215, 224, 130)
    Case "8"
      GetColor = Color.FromArgb(178, 213, 130)
    Case "9"
      GetColor = Color.FromArgb(139, 201, 128)
    Case "10"
      GetColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 189, 122)
    Case Else
      GetColor = Color.White
  End Select
End Function
```